# Adobe AEM - How to combine clientlibs on the runtime

Tags: adobe, aem, client-library

I want to combine the clientlibs on the page on runtime based on some conditions.
For eg. I have the below items on the page

```
<link href="a.css" />
<link href="b.css" />
```

If I have a condition to enable concatenation, I want to combine these two css to a single one.

```
<link href="combined.css" />
```

Is it possible with **Adobe Granite HTML Library Manager** or **HTML rewriter** or some other option?

Comment: What you can do, is create 2 client libraries. clientlb1 contains a.css and clientlib2 contains both a.css and b.css.

Then you can render the  clientlib you want based on your condition.

Comment: Thansk @AhmedMusallam. However, this is not a scalable approach, as I have hundreds of css files and each page has different conditions. I want to do it dynamically. And, the combinations can be anything.

Comment: Well, that’s now what you asked.Is this an effort to optimize css to only deliver what is needed for a particular page? If so, you might find a way to optimize it via a servlet. But Ask yourself if the css needs to be refactored instead. So you can avoid having to do it here.

Comment: You are right. Looking for an optimized css. I will not be able to do at build time as I can't know, which all AEM components will be authored on the page. Is there any example you can point? That will be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 Clientlibs and add css files accordingly.
Use "embed" property in the clientlibs to render all files combined from both clientlibs at runtime.

Or

If you want to load these files individually, create 2 different clientlibs including respective css files. Load these clientlibs based on the conditions.